# I am trying to attempt following MySQL query but not work in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
UPDATE `asset_form` SET `ASSIGN_TO` = ('Nishant Sourav') 
WHERE asset_form.ASSIGN_TO = ('Nishant SouravÂ ') LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how its not working? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0951 seconds.)

Comment: same things are updating by double-clicking on table of xampp.it contains about 200 records.

Comment: Provide more info in your question, like, what is that table schema, sample data from that table, etc.

Comment: Try This:: `SELECT ASSIGN_TO FROM asset_form LIMIT 50` Do all the 50 already have `ASSIGN_TO` set to `Nishant Sourav`

Comment: I didn't want to update the whole table. I only need to change the name of records from 'Nishant SouravÂ' to 'Nishant Sourav;

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is the Limit Clause`.
Following works just fine test in sqlfiddle
The Create insert and update has to be on the left side

```
CREATE TABLE asset_form
(`ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
 , `buyer` int
 , `seller` int
 , `ASSIGN_TO` varchar(60),
PRIMARY KEY (ID))
;

INSERT INTO asset_form
( `buyer`, `seller`, `ASSIGN_TO` )
VALUES
( 22, 12, 'test'),
( 500, 20, 'Nishant SouravÂ')
;

UPDATE asset_form
SET `ASSIGN_TO`='Nishant Sourav' 
WHERE `ASSIGN_TO` IN (
SELECT `ASSIGN_TO` FROM (
SELECT `ASSIGN_TO` From asset_form
    ORDER BY `ASSIGN_TO` ASC  
  Limit 0,1
) tmp
);
) tmp
);
```

And on the right sight

```
  Select * From asset_form;
```